# Theme ListView text pulled from XML?

Tags: application-development, themes, ubuntu-touch, qml, xml

I've been working on my msm touch app and got to a point were I get the needed info from an XML file, but it is unthemed, and not as good looking as other "direct" text is. Its black and further to the left.

This is my code to show the needed info:

```
// Server status
ListItem.ThinDivider {} //can be used as header for list
  ListItem.Standard {
    ListView {
      model: xmlModel
      delegate: Text { text: "Serverstatus " + serverState }
    }
 showDivider: false
}
```

I'm using XmlListModel to get the info.

SO. WHy is the text not like the rest, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was to deligate the outout from the XML in a ListItem like this:

```
ListView {
   width: units.gu(50)
   height: units.gu(5)
   model: minecraftBlogg
   delegate: ListItem.Subtitled {
      text: minecraftVersion
      subText: i18n.tr("Latest version")
      progression: true
      showDivider: false
  }
 }
```